# Invert sites div position without changing HTML code

Tags: html, css

I have this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/vz9cean1/

This is code HTML:

```
<div class="patrat1"></div>
<div class="patrat2"></div>
```

This is code CSS:

```
.patrat1
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}
.patrat2
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
            //some code to reverse div


}
```

How can we do when the window is less than 700px squares to change their position in between?
Red is above and blue below.

This will be done without changing HTML, CSS only.

http://i60.tinypic.com/x5tg6v.jpg
I put a picture to understand better

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check my answer might it will help you.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the only way to switch the position vertically is to use a flex container.

**CSS**:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.patrat1
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;

    order: 0;
}
.patrat2
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
  .patrat1 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="patrat1"></div>
  <div class="patrat2"></div>
</div>
```

Live example: http://www.cssdesk.com/usGck

EDIT: note that you may need to add vendor prefixes, according to Can I Use: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: +1 Alternatively you could set `.container` to `flex-direction: column-reverse;` instead of setting `order: 1;` on `.patrat1`.

Comment: exactly, depending on what the OP wants to do: if they are 2 elements, it's just the same... otherwise your methods reverses the direction, with mine he can have a more precise control over the ordering :) - NOTE: ordering starts from 0 (this is why order: 1 sets the container to the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the `css` when `max-width` is `700px`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vz9cean1/1/)

```css
.patrat1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}
.patrat2 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .patrat2 {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background:blue;
    }
    .patrat1 {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background:red;
    }
}
}
```

```html
<div class="patrat1"></div>
<div class="patrat2"></div>
```

Comment: What the heck? He asked to change the POSITION, not the color.

Comment: This is the comedy solution lol. Nice if its a background order, bad for content

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/vz9cean1/3/).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    body div {
      display: table-caption;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to swap the position of the divs, you could try something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.patrat2, .patrat1 {
 float:left;   

}
 .patrat1 {
    margin-top:100px;
}
 .patrat2 {
    margin-left:-100px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following way to switch the div.

```css
.patrat1
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}
.patrat2
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
.patrat2{
    position:absolute;
        top:10px;
}
    .patrat1{
    position:absolute;
        top:110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="patrat1"></div>
<div class="patrat2"></div>
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/vz9cean1/4/)

Note: This solution is good if there is fixed height.